# How can I get the value from the last td in the tr tag in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table when I click on a table row I can fetch the row with this but how can I get the value from the last td in the tr tag?

```
$(this); // equals my hovered tr row
```

I thought of something like this:

```
$(this:last-child).text();
```

Or should it be like this:

```
$(this + ":last-child").text(); or with .html();
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try with:

```
$(this).find(':last-child').text();
```

Or :

```
$(':last-child', this).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#' + this.id + ' :last-child').text();
```

is the same as:

```
$('#idOfMyTr :last-child').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($( "table#hello td:nth-last-child(1)" ).text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="masteries" id='hello'>
        <tr class="p0">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3,</td
        </tr>
        <tr class="p4">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3,</td
        </tr>
        <tr class="p8">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3,</td
        </tr>
    <table>
```